# Save the model as pkl file in colab content directory and reload it from there

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pickle

I ran a time-series model on colab and save the station-wise best-fitted model as a pkl file in the colab local directory, But when i tried to fectch the save model for further prediction, i am getting error that file could not be found. How to give the path for the models,

Copied path from the colab (/content/trained_modelsa.pkl)

Models are saved in the below name and fotmat

[image: Models are saved in the below]

Code i used for fetching the models,

```
from pycaret.regression import load_model, predict_model
all_score_df = []
list_ = ['a','b','c']
j = 0
for i in tqdm(df['ds'].unique()):
  l = load_model("trained_models" + list_[j], verbose=False)
  p = predict_model(l, data=score_df)
  p['time_series'] = i
  all_score_df.append(p)
  j=j+1
  concat_df = pd.concat(all_score_df, axis=0)
  concat_df.head()
```

Error line

```
"['t'] not in index" (Line no 7)
```

Comment: your model file name is 'trained_modelsa.pkl' and you are trying to find this  'trained_models2013-03-01T00:00:00.000000000.pkl'

Comment: If i remove the [i], then i getting this error 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'trained_models.pkl'

Comment: what is df['ds'] contains, I'm assuming your for loop will run three times

Comment: yes, i have three models for 3[ds] stations.

Answer (score 1):

When you store folders/files in the `/content` folder, they only persist as long as the runtime environment is active. To store folders/files directly in any of your Google Drive folders, making the files persist even if you close the running runtime, you must use the `/content/drive/MyDrive/YourFolderInDrive` path.

Specifically, to use any folder/file from your Google Drive, follow these steps:

1. Click on "Mount Drive" button and follow the steps.
2. Click on "Refresh" button.
3. Using the folder tree, scroll through the folders until you find the folder/file you want.
4. Right click the folder/file and click "Copy path". This is the path you must use in your Python code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

make a list of a,b,c and append it rather than a string(i).

```
from pycaret.regression import load_model, predict_model
all_score_df = []
for i in tqdm(df['st'].unique()):
    l = load_model("trained_models" + str(i), verbose=False)
    p = predict_model(l, data=score_df)
    p['time_series'] = i
    all_score_df.append(p)
concat_df = pd.concat(all_score_df, axis=0)
concat_df.head()
```

Comment: I am getting a new error, I updated full line of code and error code, plz check it.

Comment: I joined in the chat room